# $_POST does not get unset

Tags: php, post

scriptA.php has a form that sends POST to scriptB.php.  scriptB.php also a form that sends POST data to scriptC.php.  When I print_r($_POST) on scriptC.php, the data is not scriptB's but scriptA's!

ScriptB even has a call to unset($_POST) which seems to work.  It appears to work because on scriptB ther is also a print_r($_POST) after that unset($_POST) which shows it is empty.

So how does scriptC still end up with scriptA's POST data?  I've unset() it, and submitted a new POST form... but it's not going away! I'm going crazy here.

Tried multiple browsers, logging in and out of the site... Nothing has worked so far.

## scriptA.php

```
<form method="post" action="scriptB.php">
{form inputs}
</form>
```

## scriptB.php:

```
<?php

unset($_POST);
print_r($_POST); //blank

?>
<form method="post" action="scriptC.php">
{form inputs, different than scriptA}
</form>
```

## scriptC.php:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST); // displays data fields from scriptA instead of scriptB

?>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: try to submit scriptB form directly and see what will happen.

Comment: To reiterate the problem, because I think Jhilom was confused... ScriptC's print_r($_POST) shows data from ScriptA. This is not desired.  What I want to happen is ScriptC's print_r($_POST) to show data from ScriptB.  And you'd think this happen since ScriptB is the one submitting to ScriptC....

Comment: try  `unset($_POST);` on the scriptB.php after print_r

Comment: I think we need to see exactly what inputs are in these forms.

Comment: And the `unset(...)` shouldn't make any difference; the scope of `$_POST` parameters is only 1 request.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I completely agree.  It's very strange behavior.

Comment: It's impossible. I tested your code and `ScriptC` did not show `ScriptA`'s variables. You're obviously doing something differently, than what you posted for code. I posted an answer originally, but I deleted it after Quentin said it wouldn't work. This in regards to using `$_POST = array();` which I was wrong about. In testing, `scriptA` where I entered `fred1` in input field. `scriptB` showed nothing then entering `fred2` in the input field, clicking submit which brought me to `scriptC` and the output was `Array ( [var2name] => fred2 )` `var2name` came from `scriptB` and not `scriptA`

Answer (score -2):

Use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem here.  I do not need scriptA data on ScriptC.  It already IS appearing in ScriptC, erroneously in my opinion.  It shouldn't be. The way I have it designed/programmed, ScriptC should have POST data from scriptB, not ScriptA. but for some reaosn it does.

Comment: you wanted 1st page's data on 3rd page. But unsettling post will delete the previous data.

Comment: you misunderstood what he want and even your script is so wrong! you can't print_r inside a form field :-D at least put print_r($scriptAarrayB, 1) but still wrong

Comment: @Jhilom, you are mistaken.  Read again.  In my original post, and also in my comment to you, I stated I do NOT want 1st page's data on 3rd page.

Comment: ok I understood. I really misunderstood the problem. ok use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST. I think that will solve your problem

Comment: @Jhilom, what is your reasoning?

Comment: @Jhilom - Isn't using `$_REQUEST` considered bad practice from a security standpoint?

Comment: I think somehow your pages are blocking Post method. That is why I told you to use that